# Automatically restore last saved document on application launch

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data, nsdocument

I have a Core Data Document Based application written in swift and using storyboards. Whenever I build and launch the app, instead of automatically opening the last opened document(s), it will create a new document. What I want to be able to do is have the application automatically restore whatever documents were last opened on application launch, if they are available. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question does not involve a coding problem. The default application created by Xcode automatically supports the Resume functionality. What was blocking this from working was the System Preference:

General -> Close windows when quitting an app

This preference was selected and closed the windows of the app upon quitting which naturally means there is nothing to resume when the app relaunches.

Answer (score 0):

OS X has a feature called Resume. It does basically what you want. This way you allow your user to decide wether to open new documents or open existing ones on launch.

You can find a starting point [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW14). Use the Find command to locate the Resume part. I found an [example](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/cocoa-ui-preservation-yall/) here.

Comment: Unfortunately, there aren't enough details there to help me for my specific case. If you are aware of any sample code or WWDC videos covering this topic, I would be interested.